# How to set session userdata from database in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have problem with my session login in codeigniter 3. I can't get data from database to insert session. Whats wrong with my code?

My Controller

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();      
    $this->load->model('m_login');
}

function index(){
    $this->load->view('v_login');
}

function aksi_login(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $where = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => md5($password)
        );
    $cek = $this->m_login->cek_login("admin",$where)->num_rows();
    if($cek > 0){
        $data_session = array(
            'username' => $cek['username'],
            'nama'     => $cek['nama']
            'status'   => "login"
            );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
        redirect(base_url("admin"));
    }else{
        echo "Username dan password salah !";
    }
}
}
```

My Model

```
<?php 
class M_login extends CI_Model{ 
function cek_login($table,$where){      
    return $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you load session library ?

Comment: yes i do.
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','form_validation');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.m_login->cek_login 
  this functions returns a SQL QUERY OBJECT 
2.the SQL QUERY OBJECT ->num_rows() function returns a INT ($cek) 
3.so $cek is a INT . so u cant use like an array ($cek['username'])

so Please try this code

```
function aksi_login(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $where = array(
        'username' => $username,
       'password' => md5($password)
    );
   $cek = $this->m_login->cek_login("admin",$where);//$cek is a Query Object
   $rows = $cek->num_rows();//$rows is a INT
   if($rows > 0){
        $cek = $cek->row_array();//now u get an Array
        $data_session = array(
           'username' => $cek['username'],
           'nama'     => $cek['nama']
           'status'   => "login"
           );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
        redirect(base_url("admin"));
    }else{
        echo "Username dan password salah !";
    }
}
```

Comment: and more ...define('ENVIRONMENT','development') in /index.php. then u can see the error hint.

Comment: its glad to help you  ~

Comment: any other problems with this. Now each input can do login.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try This 
if($cek > 0){
   $cek = $cek->row_array();
    $data_session = array(
        'username' => $cek['username'],
        'nama'     => $cek['nama']
        'status'   => "login"
        );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
    redirect(base_url("admin"));
}else{
    echo "Username dan password salah !";
}
```

Comment: not work..
Fatal error: Call to a member function row_array() on integer

Comment: oh sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

In codeigniter `row_array()` takes the first matched row in array format.So your `function aksi_login()` must be like this...

```
function aksi_login(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $where = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => md5($password)
        );
    $result = $this->m_login->cek_login("admin",$where);
    $cek = $this->m_login->cek_login("admin",$where)->num_rows();
    if($cek > 0){
        $cek = $result->row_array();//no your records are in array format having matched row
        $data_session = array(
            'username' => $cek['username'],
            'nama'     => $cek['nama']
            'status'   => "login"
            );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
        redirect(base_url("admin"));
    }else{
        echo "Username dan password salah !";
    }
}
```

For more refer here..https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: not work.
Fatal error: Call to a member function row_array() on integer